# Dropbox API, how to stop upload file

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

I use the "uploadFileChunk" to upload a file,but I do not know how to stop it. I try to get the "uploadRequests" object,but failed. how to do.I am very anxious.Please help me.Thanks!

Comment: Why `[dbRestClient cancelFileUpload:@"/path/to/file"];` isn't good enough?

Comment: I tried,but it did not work!

Comment: This is my code:
if (offset < size) {
                [[self restClient] uploadFileChunk:uploadId offset:offset fromPath:path];
            } else {
                [[self restClient] uploadFile:fileName toPath:destPath withParentRev:nil fromUploadId:uploadId];
            }
And the "cancelFileUpload:" did not stop the upload task.

Comment: some info here: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=99589#post-543538